# How to customize results returned in nearby place search, Google Maps JS API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am still relatively new to Google Maps API and JS so this might (probably)
have a simple answer.

I am now returning all places within a certain radius from where my location 
is set but I want to be more specific such as only plant nursery's, fuel stations and gyms and only display those markers.

Sorry about the long code block, here is a JSBin if you'd prefer 
https://jsbin.com/yodolexece/edit?html,js,output

Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Locator</title>

    <script type="text/javascript"       
     src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBdodiLO598_RD8_NYXK7nBKNA9Fhx_uBQ&libraries=places,geometry&.js"></script>

    <script 
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <input id="findMe" type="button" value="find closest place">
      <div id="map-canvas" style="height:500px;"></div>
     </body>
    </body>
  </html>
```

JS:

```
<script>   
jQuery(function($) {
var $overlay = $('.overlay'),
  resize = true,
  map;
var service;  
var marker = [];
var pos;
var infowindow;
var placeLoc

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  // Try HTML5 geolocation
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      $('#findMe').data('pos', pos);
      var request = {
        location: pos,
        radius: 1000,
      };
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
      service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
        content: 'You Are Here'
      });
      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }

  function callback(results, status) {
    var markers = [];
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        markers.push(createMarker(results[i]));
      }
    }
    $('#findMe').data('markers', markers);
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    type: ['store'],
    position: place.geometry.location,
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      scale: 8,
      fillColor: '00a14b',
      fillOpacity: 0.3,
      fillStroke: '00a14b',
      strokeWeight: 4,
      strokeOpacity: 0.7
    },
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
  return marker;
}

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
  if (errorFlag) {
    var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
  } else {
    var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
  }

  var options = {
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
    content: content
  };
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
  map.setCenter(options.position);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

$('#show').click(function() {
  $overlay.show();
  if (resize) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    resize = false;
  }
});

$('.overlay-bg').click(function() {
  $overlay.hide();
});

$("#findMe").click(function() {
  var pos = $(this).data('pos'),
    markers = $(this).data('markers'),
    closest;
  if (!pos || !markers) {
    alert('pos or markers not set yet');
    return;
  }
  $.each(markers, function() {
    var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(this.getPosition(), pos);
    if (!closest || closest.distance > distance) {
      closest = {
        marker: this,
        distance: distance
      }
    }
  });
  if (closest) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(closest.marker, 'click')
  }
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its quite simple. You need to pass an array of types that you need to edit your request with a new attribute called types to filter. Ex types: ['bank', 'gym']

Code Block below and I will attached a modified version of your JS Bin

[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/qonowuheva/1/edit?js,output)

Places types can be find from the links below

[Place Types](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types)

Google Places API Documentation - developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests

```
var request = {
            location: pos,
            radius: 1000,
            types: ['bank', 'gym']
          };
          infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
          service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough, thought it would be easy but
that was super easy. You made my weekend.

Comment: No problem..Glad I could help you